# How to get the data of a website's "pop-up" box with Selenium Webdriver in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm a newcomer in data scraping, so I appologize in advance if my question is flawed by any reason.

I'm trying to scrap a page of an air company ([link](https://www.voegol.com.br/en-us/Paginas/Default.aspx), as to get the data of the flight (ex: aircraft type). I was successful as to enter the data for the flights (departure and arrival airports / data), and get a screen with the flight proposals.

In the second screen, there is a link called "Direct flight". I also included a code line to click on this, so a new pop-up window appears - this one, with the data I want (scheduled departure/arrival times, aircraft type).

But when I try to download it with "html = browser.page_source" (parsing with BeautifulSoup), it apparently is downloading only the content of the previous page (before clicking on "Direct flight", while I want to pick the information from the pop-up box (see [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A31Hi.jpg)).

```
voosdiretos=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('plusBus')
voo=voosdiretos[0]
voo.click()

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup_string=str(soup)
print('soup_to_string')
```

I tried to find a solution for it. Those usually recommended the use of window_handle, but there is no way I can make it work here (I suspect this pop-up windows is not an actual new pop-up, but some sort of javascript pop-up window).

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to scrap this information?

[EDIT]

Following Grasshopper's suggestion, I tried to get the elements:

```
elem_=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.informacoesLightbox bgGrid borderIe8')
print(len(elem_))
print(type(elem_))
```

Output was 0 and  (nothing was returned).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The information is not a new pop-up window as you have pointed but contained in a div which has the class `--informacoesLightbox bgGrid borderIe8`. The display attribute is toggled to make this visible when you click direct flight. You can get the rest of the data from this div using css or xpath locators because the divs inside have no ids, names etc.

CSS below --

```
Flight Name - "div[class='boxVoo'] > span[class='stsLeft']"
Operator Name - "div[class='boxVoo'] > span[class='stsRight']"
Time Duration - "div[class='boxVoo'] div[class='boxInfoLight'] div[class='timeDuration']"
Aircraft Type - "div[class='boxVoo'] div[class='rightboxInfoLight'] div:nth-of-type(1)"
Tag - "div[class='boxVoo'] div[class='rightboxInfoLight'] div:nth-of-type(2)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Grasshopper. I edited the question with more inputs (thanks in advance if you can help there).